# Makemigrations in dev machine, without database instance

Tags: django, docker, migration

I am working in my dev machine. The code is tested during development in docker containers, because:

- I have a nice `docker-compose.yml`
- I want to develop in an environment as similar to the deploy environment as possible
- I do not want to install any package system wide (specifically `postgres`): I only want in my development machine applications for development, not for testing or running applications.

Now I am trying to update my migrations:

```
» DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=xxx python manage.py makemigrations
....
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

Well, yes, of course, my host machine can not see the `postgres` container (only the running containers can see each other, as per docker compose architecture)

I could connect to the app container, make the migrations there, and retrieve the migrations to my development machine, but this does not seem a good solution.

My understanding is that the migrations are computed based on:

- the currently stored migrations, in the development repo
- the changes in the models, as compared to those migrations

I do not see why I need a database instance to make the migrations.

Can I make migrations without a connection to the database? How?

### EDIT

Adding full traceback below. From what I can see, the connection to the database is attempted by the vanilla `makemigrations` command. Why is this the case?

I am running:

```
» python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Feb 22 2018, 09:26:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.__version__
'2.0.4'
>>> 


/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: No address associated with hostname


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 92, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 275, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

### EDIT2

Running the migrations from the container works:

```
root@7dc4a3001a46:/code# python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'something':
  proj/something/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Something
```

And now I have to get this migration out of the container, to my codebase? How cumbersome is that!? I can as well run the db on my host, or maybe allow for a connection to the containerized db from the dev host.

Still not clear to me why I need to have a db connection to prepare the migrations though.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Perhaps there is some code that triggers a database query when `makemigrations` loads your code.

Comment: You can mount the volume to your migration folder in the docker-compose.yml and then run the command `docker-compose run --rm your_service python manage.py makemigrations`. Is it a problem?

Comment: @Alasdair full traceback added. It seems the db access is indeed triggered by `makemigrations`. Why?

Comment: @zstate that solution still implies that I can not prepare migrations without a working database instance. Why should that be the case? What does code development have to do with a running database?

Comment: I think if you are trying to replicate production environment as close as possible, you have to have a running database (if you have it in production). Not sure I understand why it is a problem to have running docker database instance?

Answer (score 19):

The `makemigrations` command is trying to access the database to [check the consistency](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#history-consistency) of the migrations.

[Ticket 26930](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26930) suggests that you can avoid the check by changing your settings to use the `dummy` backend.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unexpected for me. That means that I will get different migrations depending on what database I happen to be using at this moment. I expected that migrations only depend on the changes that I do to my models.

Comment: The check prevents `makemigrations` from running if there are inconsistently applied migrations. If the check passes, the database shouldn't affect the migration file that is created.